# Why is np.where not returning the expected values

Tags: python, numpy

**Initialization code**

```
arr = np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
```

**My input array is**

```
[[[[0.5, 1. ],
     [0.6, 2. ]],

    [[0. , 0. ],
     [0. , 0. ]]],


   [[[0. , 0. ],
     [0. , 0. ]],

    [[0. , 0. ],
     [0. , 0. ]]]]
```

**Command**

```
np.where(arr > 0)
```

**Output**

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

**Dimensions of the tuple**
state_0 * state_1 * action * new_state_1 * new_state_2

**Questions**

1. Why is the last value in the above tuple is not **arr[0,0,1,0]** ?
2. How to find the the new_states where values are greater than zero ?

Comment: 1) Why do you expect it to be? This looks correct to me. 2) If I understand the question correctly, `arr[np.where(arr > 0)]`.

Comment: @Amadan arr[0][1][0][1] is 0 then why is it in the output ?

Comment: Turn your head 90 degrees. The indices for each item are in _columns_, not in rows. Last row is the last index for each of the four elements, not all indices of the last element.

Comment: @Amadan , thanks that describes the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are correct, you are just reading them wrong. Each number in the first row represents the first index of the result. The second row represents the second index. So,

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

corresponds to the spots at arr[0,0,0,0], arr[0,0,0,1], and so on.

You would probably be less confused if the result was not of square shape. Try this for example:

```
np.where(arr==0)
```

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), 
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), 
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

As you can see, the rows can't correspond to the location of one unit.